# Group By - select by a criteria that is met every month

Tags: sql, postgresql

The below query returns all `USERS` that have `SUM(AMOUNT) > 10` in a given month.  It includes Users in a month even if they don't meet the criteria in other months.

But I'd like to transform this query to return all `USERS` who must meet the criteria `SUM(AMOUNT) > 10` **every single month (i.e., from the first month in the table to the last one)** across the entire data.

Put another way, exclude users who don't meet `SUM(AMOUNT) > 10` every single month.

```
select USERS, to_char(transaction_date, 'YYYY-MM') as month
from Table
GROUP BY USERS, month
HAVING SUM(AMOUNT) > 10;
```

Comment: What does "every single month" mean? Every month the user has an entry? Every month some user has an entry? Every month from the first month in the table to the last one? Every month in a certain time span, e.g. Jan 2018 to Oct 2018?

Comment: It is correct with respect to each month as you specified group by users,month meaning every single month group but the fact you have month with year in it doesnt mean for other years it will be same so if you can change your month format to Just 'MM'

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner I only want to return users who have SUM(AMOUNT) > 10 from the first month in the table to the last one i.e., all months.

Comment: What if there's a missing month for a user?

Comment: @dnoeth then they should be excluded - I'm essentially trying to build a database of consistent users

Answer (score 0):

One approach uses a generated calendar table representing all months in your data set.  We can left join this calendar table to your current query, and then aggregate over all months by user:

```
WITH months AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT TO_CHAR(transaction_date, 'YYYY-MM') AS month
    FROM yourTable
),
cte AS (
    SELECT USERS, TO_CHAR(transaction_date, 'YYYY-MM') AS month
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY USERS, month
    HAVING SUM(AMOUNT) > 10
)

SELECT
    t.USERS
FROM months m
LEFT JOIN cte t
    ON m.month = t.month
GROUP BY
    t.USERS
HAVING
    COUNT(t.USERS) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM months);
```

The `HAVING` clause above asserts that the number of months to which a user matches is in fact the total number of months.  This would imply that the user meets the sum criteria for every month.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be using `sign(amount-10)` vs. `sign(amount)` logic as

```
SELECT q.users
  FROM
    (
    with tab(users, transaction_date,amount) as
    (
     select 1,date'2018-11-24',8 union all
     select 1,date'2018-11-24',18 union all    
     select 2,date'2018-10-24',13 union all
     select 3,date'2018-11-24',18 union all    
     select 3,date'2018-10-24',28 union all
     select 3,date'2018-09-24', 3 union all    
     select 4,date'2018-10-24',28
    )
    SELECT users, to_char(transaction_date, 'YYYY-MM') as month, 
           sum(sign(amount-10)) as cnt1,
           sum(sign(amount)) as cnt2
      FROM tab t
     GROUP BY users, month
    ) q
  GROUP BY q.users  
  HAVING sum(q.cnt1) = sum(q.cnt2)
  GROUP BY q.users

  users
  -----
    2
    4
```

[***Rextester Demo***](https://rextester.com/DVJ44541)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use a correlated subquery, such as:

```
select t.*
from (select distinct table.users from table) t
where not exists 
(
    select to_char(u.transaction_date, 'YYYY-MM') as month 
    from table u 
    where u.users = t.users 
    group by month
    having sum(u.amount) <= 10
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare the number of months > 10 to the number of months between the min and the max date:

```
SELECT users, Count(flag) AS months, Min(mth), Max(mth)
FROM
 (
   SELECT users, date_trunc('month',transaction_date) AS mth, 
      CASE WHEN Sum(amount) > 10 THEN 1 end AS flag
   FROM tab t
   GROUP BY users, mth
 ) AS dt
GROUP BY users  
HAVING -- adding the number of months > 10 to the min date and compare to max
   Min(mth) + (INTERVAL '1' MONTH * (Count(flag)-1)) = Max(mth)
```

If missing months don't count it would be a simple `count(flag)  =  count(*)`

Comment: this returns dates for the min, max values (i.e., 2015-04-01 for min), not the number/count of months - is this intended?  It's not returning the correct value as is.

Comment: Well, `Count(flag) AS months` calculates the number of months. This query returns those users who had amounts > 10 from the min to the max month and no gaps. If this is not what you want you should explain why and setup a fiddle.